# Trying to connect between 2 devices using ros

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I have 2 devices one is the publisher(Device B | 169.254.1.22) is on ros1 and on the subscriber side which is the second device(Device A | 169.254.1.21) I have both ros1 and ros2. I am able to ping A from B and B from A and also able to see the list of topics of Device B on Device A, but unable to echo or run roscore.

```
RLException: Unable to contact my own server at [http://169.254.1.22:38451/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

A common cause is that the machine cannot connect to itself.  Please check
for errors by running:

    ping 169.254.1.22

For more tips, please see

    http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Below is the exports I tried
On Device A terminal

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.22:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=169.254.1.21
export ROS_IP=169.254.1.21
```

On Device B terminal

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.21:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=169.254.1.22
export ROS_IP=169.254.1.22
```

And one more thing when I ping I can do it just with IP 169.254.1.22, but for ssh I have to use username@169.254.1.22. Does this have to do something username?

After using ROS_MASTER_URI of Device B on Device A terminal and using ROS_HOSTNAME of Device A on Device A terminal I am getting warning messages as below

```
WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://169.254.1.22:11311] host is not set to this machine
```

I am seeing a list of topics but am unable to echo those topics

Thanks in advance for the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387761/trying-to-connect-between-2-devices-using-ros/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2021-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-01**:
I'm not sure (yet) how ROS 2 is involved here. The error message you show is a ROS 1 error, so I've posted a ROS 1 focused answer.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-10-01**:
Just mentioned ROS2 for debugging purpose because I have to read those ROS1 messages on ROS2 pkg on Device A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have 2 devices one is the publisher(Device B | 169.254.1.22) is on ros1 and on the subscriber side which is the second device(Device A | 169.254.1.21)
>
> [..]
>
> Below is the exports I tried On Device A terminal

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.22:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=169.254.1.22
export ROS_IP=169.254.1.22
```

You can't set `ROS_IP` to the IP of another host. That's doesn't work. `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME` describe *the host your setting them on* (ie: on "Device A" you set them to configure "Device A"s properties). Only `ROS_MASTER_URI` can point to another host.

And you don't need both `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME`. If you have working DNS for all participating hosts (ie: all hosts running ROS nodes can resolve the hostname of all other hosts running ROS nodes), use `ROS_HOSTNAME`, if you don't, use `ROS_IP`.

---

Edit:

> Below is the exports I tried
> On Device A terminal
>
> ```
> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.22:11311
> ```

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=169.254.1.21
export ROS_IP=169.254.1.21
```

> On Device B terminal
>
> ```
> export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.21:11311
> ```

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=169.254.1.22
export ROS_IP=169.254.1.22
```

This may have been unclear, but you typically only start a single `roscore` (it's possible to start more, but that's advanced usage, which I don't believe you need or should try just yet).

Choose which machine will run `roscore`, then set `ROS_MASTER_URI` to point to its IP. So if "device A" is going to run `roscore`, set `ROS_MASTER_URI` on "device B" to `http://169.254.1.21:11311` (ie: point it to "device A"). Now on the other host (ie: the one not running `roscore`), set `ROS_MASTER_URI` to point to itself, **not** to the other host.

And as I wrote earlier: you don't need both `ROS_IP` and `ROS_HOSTNAME`. Use `ROS_IP` (unless you have a working DNS server).

With `roscore` on "device A", we'd end up with:

- device A

  ```
   export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.21:11311
   export ROS_IP=169.254.1.21
  ```
- device B

  ```
   export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://169.254.1.21:11311
   export ROS_IP=169.254.1.22
  ```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-10-01**:
I tried exporting as per your recommendation but when I export ROS_MASTER_URI of Device B on Device A, I am receiving the below warning message

```
WARNING: ROS_MASTER_URI [http://169.254.1.22:11311] host is not set to this machine
```

with this warning message, I am seeing a list of topics but unable to echo on those topics.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-01**:
To get it out of the way: have you gone through [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and [ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)?

And please update your original question text with the values of `ROS_IP`, `ROS_HOSTNAME` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` for both "device A" and "device B".

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-10-01**:
Yes, I did check those links and couldn't resolve my issue.
I have a doubt with those links when they say to ssh Device. For me to ssh a device I have to use a username and IP, so do I need to include a username while exporting too?

Modifying questions might miss direct below comments. Do you still want me to modify the question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-01**:\

> Modifying questions might miss direct below comments. Do you still want me to modify the question

I don't understand what you're trying to say.

it's perfectly safe to edit an existing question. Just click the `edit` button/link underneath your current question text. And *append* your new information. Do not remove anything that's already there.

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2021-10-01**:
Thanks @gvdhoom this worked
thanks again